# Instagram API calls faster on Heroku than on local machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

I am working on a Rails app that pulls up to 100 Instagram posts at once with the media/search endpoint and displays them on a page.  The AJAX call that loads the photos takes a very long time on localhost, but once deployed to Heroku, takes much less time (10s versus 1s).  Can anyone explain why Heroku is faster?  I might not need to worry as much about caching my results.

Thanks!!

Comment: This question is too broad. It can be your server, internet connection, Instagram API servers locations or other issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major reason will be Heroku's phsyical hosting location -- I believe [Instagram hosts with Amazon's AWS service](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/11399488246/simplifying-ec2-ssh-connections) (this may have changed after the Facebook acquisition):

> Here at Instagram, we run our infrastructure on Amazon Web Services,
>   running instances on their Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2)

Heroku basically hosts through Amazon's cloud too, meaning they are ostensibly running on the same network. This will obviously cut latency down to a minimum, as well as the fact that Heroku's services are optimized for efficiency -- high speed Internet etc

---

**Cache**

Your question is really `"should I be creating a cache for Instagram data in my system?"`

The answer is `"yes"` - it's my experience you should never rely on a third party entirely, as apart from obvious latency issues, you'll also have to contend with a multitude of other problems (API outages, client bandwidth etc)

I'd personally look at storing as much data as possible in my own system. This doesn't mean to keep all in your main DB - you could utilize a `Redis` instance to store the third-party data you need